# How to call a method as a response to another method call in Java?

Tags: java

Suppose you have a Library `L.jar` which contains class `C.class` and a method `m`.

Now, you have a project which imports this library and uses the `m` method.

In the project there is class `X` with method `mX`.

What I want to do is to somehow monitor all invocations of the method `m` and invoke the method `mX` whenever method `m` gets invoked.

If I can somehow read the parameters which get passed to method `m` when invoking it, that would be awesome.

Is this possible in Java and if so, how to do it?

Comment: You can use AspectJ for this.

Comment: What prevents you to just add the method call to mM to your project code?

Comment: The wrapping mentioned by @dunni is somewhat simliar to the [Anti-Corruption Layer pattern (`softwareengineering.stackexchange.com`)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184464/what-is-an-anti-corruption-layer-and-how-is-it-used).

Comment: @dunni I simplified this problem for the purpose of this question, but, in my real project the `m` method is invoked from hundreds of places in my project, plus from hundreds of places from many other librraries that depend on the `L` library so I can not simply wrap `m` method within my `mM` method. I need to somehow monitor `m`'s invocations which should work whenever `m` gets invoked no matter from where.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches. You can either use `AspectJ` to intercept your program calls. OR You should be wrapping `L.jar` method `m` into a class of yours and expose that class to end user. end user should be using this class to invoke `m`. now you will have full control on who is calling `m` with which parameters. The downside is that user can always call `m` directly and bypass your code.